# How to Convert String to Date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have date column in my table as string type example `Feb-18`. How do I change it to date type as `01-02-2018`?

Comment: Do you want to change the actual column data type or just convert the string into a  date in a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Storing dates as string, storing 2 digit years, assuming a language - all big problems.

Answer (score 6):

Use `convert()` with add one day :

```
select convert(date, '01-' + 'Feb-18')
```

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server is pretty good about figuring out dates.  But you need a day, so:

```
select convert(date, '01-' + datecol)
```

Note:  You should be very careful about storing dates as strings.  I would recommend that you test the conversion to be sure it works for all values:

```
select datecol
from t
where try_convert(date, '01-' + datecol) is null and
      datecol is not null;
```

If this returns any rows, then you have bad dates in your data.  Oh, it would have been better to catch these by rejecting the `insert`/`update`s in the first place.  However, you might be able to figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following way.

```
Select try_cast('01-' + 'Feb-18' as Date) as [String To Date]
```